# Segmentation fault in insert(), doubly linked list on c++

Tags: c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a doubly linked list in c++, but I get an error when I try to implement an `insert()` function. This is the struct of the Node:

```
struct NodoLDL
{
   T dato;
   NodoLDL *anterior;
   NodoLDL *siguiente;

   NodoLDL(const T &elem, NodoLDL *ant = nullptr, NodoLDL *sig = nullptr):
      dato(elem),
      anterior(ant),
      siguiente(sig)
   {}
};
```

And this is the list class:

```
 template <typename T>
class LDL
{
private:
   #include "nodoldl.h"
   size_t listSize;
   NodoLDL *listFront; //head
   NodoLDL *listBack; //tail

public:
   LDL() : listSize(0), listFront(nullptr), listBack(nullptr)
   {}
   void insert(size_t position, const T &elem);
(. . .)
}
```

This is the `insert()` function I am using, but I get segmentation fault on "`temp2->anterior = temp3`"

```
template<typename T>
void LDL<T>::insert(size_t position, const T &elem)
{    
    if(empty()){

        listFront = new NodoLDL(elem); 
        listBack = listFront;
        listSize+=1;

    }else if(listSize>0 && position==0){ //push_front()

        //The implementation for push_front() works fine.

    }else if(position==listSize){ //push_back()

        //The implementation for push_back() also works fine.           

    }else if(position > 0 && position<listSize){

        NodoLDL *temp1, *temp2, *temp3;
        temp1 = listFront;

        for(size_t i=0; i<position; i++){
            temp1 = temp1->siguiente;
        }

        temp2 = temp1->siguiente;
        temp3 = new NodoLDL (elem);
        temp1 -> siguiente = temp3;
        temp3 -> anterior = temp1;
        temp3 -> siguiente = temp2;
        temp2 -> anterior = temp3;

        listSize+=1;

    }else if(position > listSize){
        throw invalid_argument("insert() on invalid position");
    }
}
```

Insert at the beginning and at the end works, but it doesn't if I insert in the middle of the list, how can I fix it? Why is that logic wrong?
I am not sure if it is only that line or all the logic in `else if(position>0 && position<listSize)` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first and foremost you have to check if you only have one element on the list. In that case you cannot do:

```cpp
    temp2 = temp1->siguiente;
    temp3 = new NodoLDL (elem);
    temp1 -> siguiente = temp3;
    temp3 -> anterior = temp1;
    temp3 -> siguiente = temp2;
    temp2 -> anterior = temp3;
```

If you do such thing `temp1->siguiente` would be a null pointer, and as such, `temp2` will also be a null pointer. Your segmentation fault will occur when you call `temp2->anterior`. Since you will be accesing to a field where there is nothing.

I will encourage you to try and always separate this kind of procedure in different functions. One for push-back and one for push-front to call either in the first if.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void LDL<T>::insert(size_t position, const T &elem) {   

    if (position > listSize) { //I tend to always check this things first
        throw invalid_argument("insert() on invalid position");
    }

    if (empty() || position == 0) {
        push_front(elem);
        return;
    }

    if (position == listSize){ //push_back()           
        push_back(elem)
        return;
    }

    NodoLDL *temp1, *temp2, *temp3;
    temp1 = listFront;

    for(size_t i=0; i<position; i++){
        temp1 = temp1->siguiente;
    }

    temp2 = temp1->siguiente;
    temp3 = new NodoLDL (elem);
    temp1 -> siguiente = temp3;
    temp3 -> anterior = temp1;
    temp3 -> siguiente = temp2;
    temp2 -> anterior = temp3;

    listSize++;
}
```

In theory your insert should work in any case, but I understand if you're just starting to learn and see the solution better this way. Linus Torvalds has a nice TedTalk where he talks about writting beautiful code and I think the example he choses for that class is a list insert.